# How to quantify magnitude of change in dataset containing base values of 0?

Tags: statistics, normalization, geostatistics

I have a dataset with the low-water and high-water surface area of lakes/ponds within a delta for each year. These lakes can undergo substantial change from year to year, and sometimes can dry out completely. As such, surface area can have values of 0 during the low-water period. I'm trying to quantify the magnitude of flooding in the spring on the surface areas of these lakes. Given the high inter annual variations in surface area, I need to compare the low-water value from the previous year to the high-water value of the following year to quantify this magnitude; comparing to a mean isn't sensitive enough. However, given the low water surface area of 0 for some lakes, I cannot quantify percent change.

My current idea is to do an "inverse" of percent change (don't know how else to describe it), where I divide the low-water value by the high-water value. This gives me a scale where large change will equal 0 and little change will equal 1. However, again small changes from a surface area of 0 will be over represented. Any idea how I could accurately compare the magnitude of flooding in such a case?

Comment: Maybe look at increase from low water to high water divided by mean water level. Or maybe just the absolute value of high minus low. It occurs to me that volume may be more interesting than area, although volume is probably harder to measure. Note that this question is off topic here; try stats.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I will explore what you've mentioned and check the stats forum. Cheers.